# Add a date-time description in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

How do I create a **date-time** description like this, in `discord.js`? I tried to use `timestamp` but it adds the date to the footer
 [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the *new* (over half a year old by now) timestamp formatting syntax.
From the [official documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting):

### Formats

| Type | Structure | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| .... | .... | .... |
| Unix Timestamp | <t:TIMESTAMP> | <t:1618953630> |
| Unix Timestamp (Styled) | <t:TIMESTAMP:STYLE> | <t:1618953630:d> |

Timestamps will display the given timestamp in the user's timezone and locale.

### Timestamp Styles

| Style | Example Output | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t | 16:20 | Short Time |
| T | 16:20:30 | Long Time |
| d | 20/04/2021 | Short Date |
| D | 20 April 2021 | Long Date |
| f * | 20 April 2021 16:20 | Short Date/Time |
| F | Tuesday, 20 April 2021 16:20 | Long Date/Time |
| R | 2 months ago | Relative Time |

* default