# Is there any way to get the local time of a guild member with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, timezone

I am creating a Discord bot with Python that will help members of a guild set reminders. However, getting the right timezones is the biggest problem that I am facing. For now, I am using `message.created_at` to get the time (but it's in UTC - as mentioned in their docs). But, calling `message.created_at.timestamp()` returns a timestamp that has a timezone that depends on the machine the bot is being run on. When I am running the bot on my local machine, the function `message.created_at.timestamp()` returns the time with my local timezone info. But, running the bot on Heroku returns UTC as the timezone. So, I would like to know what options do I have to solve this problem? I could ask members for a timezone and save that to a database but a Discord guild might have several members residing in several different timezones, so setting a general timezone will not work for every member.

So, is there any way I can automatically detect the local time a member is sending a message in so that I can set the reminder correctly for that member?

Comment: Does the reminder work like an alarm? So, you can set a time e.g. 4p.m. and the bot sends a reminder when it's 4p.m. or is it a like a timer, so you can set it should remind me about something in x minutes?

Comment: It can work like both. Saying "remind me to do this in 5 hours" works okay because this time will be relative and kinda independent of timezones. Just make the bot send a message 5 hours after the reminder command was sent. But the main issue arises when someone says "remind me to do this tomorrow evening at 7:30"; this is when getting the right timezones is imperative.

Comment: yeah, exactly. You can achieve it a little with [`Guild.region`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20guild#discord.Guild.region) which gives you the voice region. But that's not really accurate. Otherwise I can't think of something else except of add an argument which allows the user to pass the timezone in which he lives.

Comment: You can have a setting that allows the user to tell the bot their timezone and store that in a database. Otherwise, it is not possible to know a user's timezone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a date-time description in discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71265728/add-a-date-time-description-in-discord-js)

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs it actually doesn't. Like I said, calling `message.created_at.timestamp()` doesn't contain the timezone of the message author but rather the timezone of the machine on which the bot is being run on. Hence running the bot on Heroku returns UTC

Comment: The timestamps in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71266359/16177247) are local to the user who sees it. It will convert the time you choose (in UTC let's say) to their local time. You can use the "Relative" flag to have it say "in 5 hours".

Comment: It's not possible to get a user's timezone right now (there might be functionality in slash commands but I'm not sure). You can however have a command to set their timezone (like `setmytime utc` or similar), or have them pass it in as an argument.